# Find missing character from string based on array element

Tags: python

So I have to create a project that detect missing character from a string based on array element and ended up with this:

```
vital = ['gmail','@','com','.']
text = "Dan@gmail"

for i in text.split():
    for j in vital:
        if i not in j:
            print('Missing Character: ', )
```

In this case I was approaching for `com .` to be print since these character does not contains in the 'text' string, but I couldn't think further to construct this approach, please provide a code to build what I was desired and explanation for it. Thanks.

Comment: `text.split()` doesn’t do what you want. It will give you the characters in `text` one by one, and the only character in that list that is also in `vital` is `"@"`. Instead try looping through `vital` and checking each element to see if it in `text`. But it's not a great validator. It will pass `...@Dan.gmail`. You should not be doing this yourself. Validating an email address is harder than it looks. Look at the `email` library module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```py
vital = ['gmail','@','com','.']
text = "Dan@gmail"

for e in vital:
    if e not in text:
        print('Missing Character: ',e)
```

This will output:

```
Missing Character:  com
Missing Character:  .
```

in this case

How this works:
Basically the for loop is just a foreach element in vital. If this element isn't in the string, print that it's missing